# How can I make one Tab Bar button refer to two views/controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm developing an iOS app just now with a Tab Bar navigation.

I have two screens which show the same information but in different formats (say, list and grid).

The two screens are different enough that they require separate controllers.

Users can toggle between the two views from a shared control bar button (**toggle**) at the top.

Scenario:

User presses the 'Places' button for the first time and it shows the places as a list. 
They press 'grid' to see the same places displayed as a grid.
The user presses another tab bar button to navigate to a different screen. 
When they press the "Places" button again, the app remembers their last viewed screen for places was the grid so the grid view is shown. 
The user may then toggle back to list view. etc...

Can anybody recommend the best approach to achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use one view controller that manages both views. That way, you don't have to bother with synchronizing data or subverting the normal function of UITabBarController -- there's just one controller. Also, don't try to overload the meaning of the tab for that controller. Instead, add a button to both views that tells the controller to switch to the other view. That'll be easier for your to build, and (more importantly) easier for the user to understand. It's not nice to make familiar controls do unfamiliar tricks.

If your view controllers are such that combining them into one would be complicated, then you can use two controllers and simply swap them in and out of the tab bar by modifying the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array. You can still avoid having to sync data between them by having both controllers refer to the same data model.

Comment: Am I right in saying then, if only one of these views is a table view, that the controller class should not inherit from `UITableViewController`? In this case then it's better to add a protocol?

Comment: Does this break iOS best-practices (having one controller control two view hierarchies)?

Comment: @bodacious After thinking about it a bit more, I've updated my answer. If the two views are so different that they interact with the view controller differently, then you're probably right that it makes sense to have separate controllers. I'd still avoid using the tab to toggle between the two controllers, though -- that'd just be confusing for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve this same thing, and it can actually be done with a basic setup of a TabBarController, NavigationControllers, ViewControllers, push segues, and unwinds.

```
TabBarController
   |==> NavigationController --> PlacesController(grid view) --(push segue from nav bar)--> PlacesController(list view)
   |==> NavigationController --> OtherController
   |...
```

Make sure to have an unwind segue back from the list view controller to the grid view controller.

If you toggle between views then go to another tab (e.g. otherController) and come back, you'll return to the last view you were seeing because that's what is at the top of the stack of the NavigationController.